# How to show that these sets are equal?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $E$ be the set whose subsets only we’ll be talking of. Now complementation is a bijection on $\mathcal{P} (E)$. Hence the following two sets seem intuitively equal: \begin{align}& \{ x\in E: \forall X(X\in \mathcal{C} \rightarrow x\in X)\} \text{; and,}\\ & \{ x\in E: \forall X(X’\in \mathcal{C} \rightarrow x\in X’)\}.\\ \end{align}

Here, $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{P} (E)$.

How to show formally that they are indeed equal?
($X’$ means relative complement of $X$ in $E$.)

Comment: What's $\cal C$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila $\cal C$ is just another subset of $E$.

Comment: Seems like the kind of information that would be nice to have when you're asking a question... But it also makes the formulas you're talking about pretty incoherent and unclear. What's $x$, then? Are the subsets of $E$ also elements of $E$? How do you quantify over $\cal C$?

Comment: Okay. My apologies. I’ll edit.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Now?

Comment: $\cal C$ is still free.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Now? (I’ve learnt a lot from you, including posting questions. Thanks!)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Well noticed! I’ve edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the two sets are equal is the same as showing for arbitrary $x, \mathcal C, E$:

$$ \big[ \forall X(X\in \mathcal{C} \rightarrow x\in X) \bigr] \iff 
\big [ \forall X(X’\in \mathcal{C} \rightarrow x\in X’) \bigr] $$

Let's do the $\Longleftarrow$ direction of this; the other is similar. So we're assuming $$ \tag{a} \forall X(X'\in \mathcal{C} \rightarrow x\in X')$$
Now we're given a particular $X$ and we must then show
$$ \tag{g} X\in\mathcal{C} \to x\in X. $$

The $X$ in (a) is a dummy variable, so its name does not matter, and the assumption is the same as
$$ \tag{b} \forall Y(Y'\in \mathcal{C} \rightarrow x\in Y')$$
Now instantiate (b) by substituting $X'$ for $Y$ in the scope of $\forall Y$, which gives us
$$ X''\in\mathcal{C} \to x \in X'' $$
But -- at least under the tacit assumption that $X\subseteq E$ -- we have $X''=X$ so this is the same as (g), which was what we needed to prove. We're done!

Comment: If it were $\exists$ instead of $\forall$, then also would we have got the same conclusion?

Comment: I think yes because $\exists xP(x)$ is same as $\neg \forall x\neg P(x)$.